# Is DotNetopenAuth good to get user credentials?

Tags: c#, dotnetopenauth

I want to ccreate a website that reads one's Gmails headers.

If I use dotNetopenAuth to authenticate - 
will I eventually get the user user and password for my applications' needs?

It seems that the answer is no- for security reasons that's why OpenId is for.

But then, I know website that do so. How?

Comment: here is a link with an example on how to use dotNetOpenAuth http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/csharp/2/10325264/gmail-account-login-through-aspnet-page.aspx

Comment: I need authentication or autherization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use protocols like OpenID or OAuth, you will not have access to the user's userid nor password.

Instead you will receive a unique identifier for the user, which does nothing more than tell you that the trusted provider has validated that the user logged into their provider's account successfully. It is your job to match that unique identifier with your application's user record.

Depending on the provider you use for authentication (Google, Yahoo, MyOpenId, Twitter, etc.), you may request additional information such as the user's email address and name, but you are not guaranteed to get even that.

Under no circumstances will you ever get to see their password, though. If you want that, then you will have to write your application to use your own authentication provider, like the built-in [ASP.NET Membership provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The point of OpenID is as you say: delegate authentication to another so that you don't have to deal with the password (if there even is one).

Sites that have the user log in with Google, and then gain access to that user's data at Google aren't just using OpenID.  They're also using another *authorization* protocol.  Google supports a proprietary one and a more common standard one called OAuth.  OpenID and OAuth can be combined such that the user visits Google just once to log in, and then your site gains the access it needs (if the user approves).

If you take a look at the DotNetOpenAuth sample OpenIdRelyingPartyWebForms\loginPlusOAuth.aspx you'll see an example of the user logging into Google, and by doing that giving the site the ability to download the user's Google address book.  This can be easily changed to include permissions to do other things (like read email headers) but you'll need to read Google documentation ([GData](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/)) to learn what scope to use and APIs to call to obtain this information.

Under no circumstances should you be collecting the user's Google password yourself.  I suspect that would be a violation of the Google terms of service anyway.